# TypeDoc a few documentations from one project

Tags: typescript, gruntjs, documentation, typedoc

I have to use a TypeDoc to prepare documentation of my project.

In my project I have a few folders (not related with eachother) with TS files, ex. folder A, folder B, etc.

I was very simple when I wanted only one documentation from one or more folders but it quite hard for me to generate a seperated documentations for each folder.

For one folder my config file looks like:

```
typedoc: {
    build: {
        options: {
            module: 'commonjs',
            out: '../Documentation/A',
            name: 'Documentation for A folder',
            target: 'es5',
            exclude: '**/*.d.ts',
            excludePrivate: true,
            mode: 'file'
        },
        src: [
            'js/A/*.ts'
        ]
    }
}
```

I have not idea how this config should be build if I want to a separated documentations for each of my folders.

I tried array of builds something like that (but without success):

```
typedoc: {
    build: [{
        options: {
            module: 'commonjs',
            out: '../Documentation/A',
            name: 'Documentation for A folder',
            target: 'es5',
            exclude: '**/*.d.ts',
            excludePrivate: true,
            mode: 'file'
        },
        src: [
            'js/A/*.ts'
        ]
    },
    {
        options: {
            module: 'commonjs',
            out: '../Documentation/B',
            name: 'Documentation for B folder',
            target: 'es5',
            exclude: '**/*.d.ts',
            excludePrivate: true,
            mode: 'file'
        },
        src: [
            'js/B/*.ts'
        ]
    }]
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved my problem by myself.
When I need to a few builds I should to create my config file like that:

```
typedoc: {
    buildA: {
        options: {
            module: 'commonjs',
            out: '../Documentation/A',
            name: 'Documentation for A folder',
            target: 'es5',
            exclude: '**/*.d.ts',
            excludePrivate: true,
            mode: 'file'
        },
        src: [
            'js/A/*.ts'
        ]
    },
    buildB: {
        options: {
            module: 'commonjs',
            out: '../Documentation/B',
            name: 'Documentation for B folder',
            target: 'es5',
            exclude: '**/*.d.ts',
            excludePrivate: true,
            mode: 'file'
        },
        src: [
            'js/B/*.ts'
        ]
    }
}
```

and I should to call it something like that:

```
typedoc:buildA
```

or

```
typedoc:buildB
```

that's all :)